# Cheated dice/die question probability

Tags: probability

The gaming engineer Kalle has produced a cheat die that always shows a six. He also has three regular die that are very similar to the die. Kalle and Sara will make a throw each with three die. Kalle, of course, uses the die plus two regular die, while Sara, who is unfamiliar with the die, randomly selects three of Kelle's four die. What is the probability that Sara and Kalle will get: 1) two sixes? 2) at least two sixes?

Comment: Sixes? Sexes means something different.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that Sara gets two sixes, and the probability that Kalle gets two sixes, or the probability that among all 6 rolls there are two sixes?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Show us what you've tried to do to answer the question and where you got stuck.

Comment: I'm asking for the probability that Sara and Kalle will get 1) two six 2)at least two sixes

Comment: My brain got stuck and couldn't manage to find a way to the solution